# propblem with Link in next js with type script: The prop `href` expects a `string` or `object` in `<Link>`, but got `undefined` instead

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

i have this code about Customized link component, i did this by type script:

```
...
const NavLink: React.FC<{
  activeClassName: string;
  className: string;
  href: string;
  clickEvent?: MouseEventHandler;
  onClick?: MouseEventHandler;
  title: string;
}> = (children, props) => {...}
```

this is my link component line:

```
<Link href={props.href} onClick={props.clickEvent} passHref>
```

this how i call the component:

```
<NavLink
                href='/'
                className={styles.navlink}
                activeClassName={styles.navlink__active}
                title='my link'
              />
```

i got the error in title.
any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because of the way you received the `props` from your component.

When using React, you must always receive the props as the first parameter of the functional component.

In your case, you first received `children` and then `props` as the second parameter, but this should be only one parameter because the `children` property is also received as props.

An easy way to fix that is desestructuring the `children` and using the `rest operator` to still receive the rest of the props as a variable named `props`, like the following example:

```
const NavLink: React.FC<{
  activeClassName: string;
  className: string;
  href: string;
  clickEvent?: MouseEventHandler;
  onClick?: MouseEventHandler;
  title: string;
}> = ({ children, ...props }) => {...}
```

This should keep the variables with the same name, but now you would be desestructuring both the children and all the props from the first parameter of the Functional Component.

Comment: i tryed and get Property 'children' does not exist on type '{ activeClassName: string; className: string; href: string; clickEvent?: MouseEventHandler<Element> | undefined; onClick?: MouseEventHandler<Element> | undefined; title: string; }'

Comment: i have a check of: {children !== undefined && children}

Comment: @michael it must be because React.FC does not add the children type to its props anymore. You can add the types like that: `children: React.ReactNode` and TypeScript should stop giving you that error.